# How to get rid of some lines in the otterCV?

Tags: cv, letters

I have been using the otterCV template on Overleaf in order to write a letter and I can't remove the highlighted line from the template :

[image]

I am using multiple folds in Overleaf and these are my folds :

**main.tex**:

```
%%% use 'massive', 'fancy' or 'basic' as otterCV options
%%% use 'german' for German dates, names etc.

%%% CONTACT DETAILS
\name{Ibrahim}{Otter}
\adress{Estuary Drive 12}{22850 Riverside}
\email{please@otter.me}
% \website{otters.org}
\phone{1}{23 456 789}
\born[Riverside]{1994-6-3}
% \pathtopicture[size=40mm]{static/profile.png}
\pathtopicture[size=40mm]{static/otter.jpg}

%%% SIGNATURE
\pathtosignature[xshift=3mm, yshift=-5mm]{static/signature.png}
\city{Riverside}

%%% GEOMETRY
% \usepackage[]{showframe}

\begin{document}

\input{letters/cover}
\signature[name=true, date=false, hspace=1cm, vspace=10mm]
\listofattachments

\maketitle
\input{cv/profile}
\signature[hspace=1cm, vspace=5mm]

\attachment[header=true]{\en{Motivational letter}\de{Motivationsschreiben}}
\input{letters/motivation}

\attachment{\de{Zeugnis}\en{School certificate}}
\includepdf{attachments/certificate}

\end{document}
```

**ottercv.cls** :

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ottercv}[OtterCV]

\LoadClass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\RequirePackage{fontawesome5}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, fit, positioning}

\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep, noitemsep}
\setlist[itemize]{label=\tiny\raisebox{1ex}+}

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0.14, 0.27, 0.52}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.6,0.1,0.4}

\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
   \tocloftpagestyle{empty}
   \renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
   \cftpagenumbersoff{table}
   \renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{%
       \par\vfill\hspace{-1cm}
       \vbox to 0pt{\hbox to\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm\relax{\dotfill}\vss}\\[8pt]
       \underline}
   \cftafterlottitleskip8pt
   \cftbeforelottitleskip8pt

\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, right=3cm, left=3cm]{geometry}
\newlength{\vindent}\vindent0cm
\newlength{\vleft}\vleft2cm
\newlength{\picsize}\picsize45mm

%%%%%%%%%% PICTURE %%%%%%%%%% 
\pgfkeys{
   /picture/.cd,
   xshift/.initial={0cm},
   yshift/.initial={0cm},
   zoom/.initial={1.3},
   size/.code=\picsize#1,
   }

\newcommand*{\pathtopicture}[2][]{%
   \pgfkeys{/picture/.cd,#1}%
   \def\@pathtopicture{#2}}

%%%%%%%%%% INFORMATION %%%%%%%%%% 
\title{Curriculum vitae}
\date{\today}
\newcommand*{\name}[2]{%
   \def\@firstname{#1}\def\@lastname{#2}%
   \author{\@firstname~\@lastname}
   }
\newcommand*{\theme}[1]{\def\@theme{#1}} \def\@theme{blue}
\newcommand*{\adress}[3][]{\def\@careof{#1}\def\@street{#2}\def\@zip{#3}} \let\@street\@empty \let\@zip\@empty\let\@careof\@empty
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\def\@email{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}} \let\@email\@empty
\newcommand*{\born}[2][]{\def\@birthday{\DTMdate{#2}}
                        \def\@born{\@birthday\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{}{~in~#1}}} 
                        \let\@born\@empty \let\@birthday\@empty
\newcommand*{\phone}[2]{\def\@phone{\href{tel:+#1#2}{{\tiny\raisebox{1ex}+}#1 #2}}} \let\@phone\@empty
\newcommand*{\website}[1]{\def\@website{\href{#1}{#1}}} \let\@website\@empty
\let\adressfont\textnormal

\def\ADRESS{adress}
\def\EMAIL{e-mail}
\def\PHONE{phone}
\def\BORN{born~}
\def\WEBSITE{website}
\def\@coverletter{Cover letter}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

%%%%%%%%%% REDESIGN STRUCTURE %%%%%%%%%% 
\catcode`\@=11
\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 6pt depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern\z@}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\Large\bfseries\color{\@theme}}{}{0pt}{}[\hspace{12pt}\hrulefill\newline\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}]
\titlespacing*{\section}{-\vindent}{1cm}{-6pt}
   
\titleformat{\paragraph}[block]{}{}{0cm}{}[\vspace{-1\baselineskip}]
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{-\vindent}{12pt}{0cm}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]{}{}{0cm}{\underline}[]
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0cm}{6pt}{0cm}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{}{}{0cm}{\bfseries}[]
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0cm}{6pt}{0cm}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}[block]{}{}{0cm}{}[]
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{0cm}{6pt}{0cm}
   
\def\curriculumvitae{}
%%%%%%%%%% POSSIBLE LAYOUTS %%%%%%%%%% 
\DeclareOption{massive}{%
   \let\adressfont\textbf
   \def\curriculumvitae{%
       \vindent5cm\vleft2cm
       \setstretch{1}\pagestyle{empty}
       \newgeometry{left=\dimexpr\vleft+\vindent\relax, right=\vleft, top=1cm, bottom=1cm}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
           \coordinate (corner) at  ($(current page.north west) - (0,\picsize+2cm)$);
           \filldraw[\@theme] (current page.north east) rectangle  (corner);
           \coordinate (write) at  ($(current page.north west) + (\vleft,-1cm)$);
           \coordinate (picture) at  ($(current page.north east) - (\vleft,1cm)$);
           \begin{scope}
               \clip [rounded corners=.5cm] ($(picture)-(0.75\picsize,\picsize)$) rectangle coordinate (center) (picture); 
               \node [inner sep=0pt] at ($(center)+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/picture/xshift},\pgfkeysvalueof{/picture/yshift})$) {\includegraphics[height=\pgfkeysvalueof{/picture/zoom}\picsize]{\@pathtopicture}}; 
           \end{scope}
           \node[anchor=north west, text width=0.5\paperwidth] (header) at (write)
               {\color{white} 
               {\Huge \textbf{\@author} \vspace{0.5cm}}\\ 
                \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
                    \textbf{\ADRESS} & \@street \\ 
                                    & \@zip \\
                    \textbf{\PHONE}& \@phone \\
                    \textbf{\EMAIL}& {\@email} \\
                  %  \textbf{\WEBSITE}& {\@website} \\
                    \textbf{\BORN}& \@born
                \end{tabular}
                };
       \end{tikzpicture}\vspace{\dimexpr\picsize+0.5cm\relax}
   }
}

\DeclareOption{fancy}{%
   \let\adressfont\textit
   \def\curriculumvitae{%
       \vindent45mm\vleft25mm
       \newgeometry{left=\dimexpr\vleft+\vindent\relax, right=\vleft, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}
       \setstretch{1}\pagestyle{empty}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       \coordinate (right) at ($(current page.north east) - (\vleft,2cm)$);
       \coordinate (left) at ($(current page.north west) + (\vleft,-2cm)$);
       \coordinate (down) at ($(right)-(0.75\picsize,\picsize)$);
       \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt] (picture) at (right) {%
           \begin{tikzpicture}
               \clip[rounded corners=.5cm] (0,0) rectangle coordinate (middle) (-0.75\picsize,-\picsize); 
               \node[anchor=center] at ($(middle)+(\pgfkeysvalueof{/picture/xshift},\pgfkeysvalueof{/picture/yshift})$) {\includegraphics[height=\pgfkeysvalueof{/picture/zoom}\picsize]{\@pathtopicture}};
           \end{tikzpicture}
           };
       \node [draw=\@theme,rounded corners=0.5cm,line width=1pt, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,fit=(picture)] {};
       \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0cm] (header) at (left) {\Huge\color{\@theme!60} {\textbf{\@firstname} \color{\@theme} \textbf{\@lastname}}};
       \node (H) at ($(left)-(1mm,9mm)$) [circle,fill, color=\@theme,inner sep=.5mm]{};
       \coordinate (I) at (H-|picture.west);
       \draw[line width=1pt, color=\@theme]  (H) -- (I);
%       \draw[line width=1pt, color=\@theme]  (H) -- ++(\dimexpr\paperwidth-6.5cm-0.75\picsize\relax, 0);
       \node[anchor=north east, align=left, inner sep=0cm] (contact) at ($(I)-(5mm,2mm)$){%
           \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{.5\tabcolsep}}l@{}}
               \ifx\@careof\@empty\else%
                   \multicolumn{2}{l}{\adressfont{\@careof}}\\
               \fi%
               \multicolumn{2}{l}{\adressfont{\@street}}\\
               \multicolumn{2}{l}{\adressfont{\@zip}}\\
               \faUser &\adressfont{\@birthday} \\
               \faPhone* &\adressfont{\@phone} \\
               \faEnvelope[regular] &{\adressfont{\@email}}
           \end{tabular}
           };
       \end{tikzpicture}\vspace{\dimexpr\picsize-5mm\relax}
       }
   \titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\color{\@theme}}{\rule[2pt]{\dimexpr\vindent-0.5cm\relax}{3pt}\hspace{0.5cm}}{0pt}{}[]
   \titlespacing*{\section}{-\vindent}{1cm}{6pt}
}

\DeclareOption{basic}{%
   \theme{gray}
   \def\curriculumvitae{%
       \vindent5cm\setstretch{1}\pagestyle{empty}
       \newgeometry{left=\dimexpr\vleft+\vindent\relax, right=\vleft, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}
       
       {\Huge \color{gray} \textsf{\textbf{\@firstname} \color{black} \textbf{\@lastname} }}\\[12pt]
       \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
       \textbf{\ADRESS} & \@street \\ 
       & \@zip \\
       \textbf{\PHONE}& \@phone \\
       \textbf{\EMAIL}& {\@email} \\
       \textbf{\BORN}& \@born
       \end{tabular}
   }
}

%%%%%%%%%% add LANGUAGES here: %%%%%%%%%% 
\DeclareOption{german}{%
   \PassOptionsToPackage{main=ngerman}{babel}
   \renewcommand{\ADRESS}{Adresse}
   \renewcommand{\EMAIL}{E-Mail}
   \renewcommand{\PHONE}{Telefon}
   \renewcommand{\BORN}{geboren am~}
   \renewcommand{\WEBSITE}{Webseite}
   \renewcommand{\@coverletter}{Anschreiben}
   \title{Lebenslauf}
   \newcommand{\DTMngermanshortmonthname}[1]{%
               \ifcase#1
               \or Jan%
               \or Feb%
               \or Mär%
               \or Apr%
               \or Mai%
               \or Jun%
               \or Jul%
               \or Aug%
               \or Sep%
               \or Okt%
               \or Nov%
               \or Dez%
               \fi}%
   }

\ProcessOptions\relax

%%%%%%%%%% LANGUAGE UPDATE %%%%%%%%%% 
\RequirePackage{iflang}
\RequirePackage[british]{babel}
\RequirePackage[useregional, calc]{datetime2}
\RequirePackage{translator}

\newcommand{\de}[1]{\IfLanguageName{ngerman}{#1}{}}
\newcommand{\en}[1]{\IfLanguageName{british}{#1}{}}

\addto\captionsbritish{%
   \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Attachments:}
   \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Overview}%
}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
   \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Anhang:}
   \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Übersicht}%
}

\newcommand{\MONTH}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DTMshortmonthname{#1}}{}}
\newcommand{\DATE}[1]{\DTMdate{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%% SIGNATURE %%%%%%%%%% 
\pgfkeys{
   /signature/.cd,
   xshift/.initial={0cm},
   yshift/.initial={0cm},
   zshift/.initial={5mm},
   size/.initial={2cm},
}
   
\newcommand*{\city}[1]{\def\@city{#1}}
\newcommand*{\pathtosignature}[2][]{%
   \pgfkeys{/signature/.cd,#1}%
   \def\@pathtosignature{#2}}

\newcommand*{\signature}[1][]{%
   \pgfkeys{
       /signature/.cd,
       vspace/.initial={0cm},
       hspace/.initial={0cm},
       date/.initial={true},
       name/.initial={false},
       #1
   }
   \par
   \vspace{\dimexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/signature/vspace}+1cm\relax}
   \hspace{\dimexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/signature/hspace}-\vindent-4pt\relax}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
   \coordinate (center) at (0,0);
   \draw[thick] (center) -- ++(6,0);
   \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] (signature) at (\pgfkeysvalueof{/signature/xshift},\pgfkeysvalueof{/signature/yshift}) {\includegraphics[height=\pgfkeysvalueof{/signature/size}]{\@pathtosignature}};
   \ifthenelse{\boolean{\pgfkeysvalueof{/signature/date}}}{%
       \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0] (date) at (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/signature/zshift}) {\@city,~\IfLanguageName{ngerman}{den~}{}\@date};
       }{}
   \ifthenelse{\boolean{\pgfkeysvalueof{/signature/name}}}{%
       \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (name) at (0,0 |- signature.north) {\@author};
       }{}
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
   
%%%%%%%%%% LETTERS %%%%%%%%%% 
\newcommand{\subject}[1]{\def\@subject{#1}}\let\@subject\@empty
\newcommand{\recepient}[1]{\def\@recepient{#1}}\let\@recepient\@empty

\newlength{\lettersep}\lettersep5mm
\newlength{\letterind}\letterind10mm 

\pgfkeys{
   /letter/.cd,
   vspace/.code=\lettersep#1,
   hspace/.code=\letterind#1,
   sender/.initial={true},
   stretch/.initial=1,
}

\newcommand{\coverletter}[1][]{%
   \pgfkeys{/letter/.cd,#1}\vindent0cm
       \part[attachment=false]{\@coverletter}
       \newgeometry{vmargin=2cm, hmargin=3cm}
       \hspace{\dimexpr-3pt-\letterind\relax}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[text width=\dimexpr\textwidth+\letterind\relax, anchor=north west, align=right, inner sep=0cm, font=\small] (head) at (0,0){%
               \@author \\ 
               \ifx\@careof\@empty \else \@careof\\ \fi%
               \@street \\ \@zip \\
               %\PHONE: 
               \@phone \\
               %\EMAIL:
               {\@email}
               };
       \node[anchor=north west, text width=\textwidth,inner sep=0pt] (adress) at ($(-\letterind,0|-head.south)-(0,2\lettersep)$) {%
           \ifthenelse{\boolean{\pgfkeysvalueof{/letter/sender}}}{\textsf{\underline{\@author, \ifx\@careof\@empty \else \@careof, \fi \@street, \@zip}}\\[1.5\lettersep]}{}%
           \@recepient};
       \node[anchor=north west, text width=\textwidth,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0|-adress.south) {\vspace{3\lettersep}\par{\raggedleft\@date\\[2\lettersep]} \par \textbf{\@subject}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
}

%%%%%%%%%% STRUCTURE %%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{partpage}
\renewcommand{\part}[2][]{%
   \pgfkeys{/structure/.cd,
       stretch/.initial={1},
       header/.initial={false},
       attachment/.initial={true},
       #1}
   \newpage\phantomsection\restoregeometry
   \ifthenelse{\boolean{\pgfkeysvalueof{/structure/header}}}
       {% (true) : header 
           \pagestyle{fancy}
           \setcounter{partpage}{\thepage}
           \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
           \fancyhf{}
           \chead{#2}
           \cfoot{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral \the\numexpr\value{page}-\value{partpage}+1@}
       }{% (false) : no header 
           \pagestyle{empty}
       }
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#2}
   \ifthenelse{\boolean{\pgfkeysvalueof{/structure/attachment}}}{%
   \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{$\bullet$\hspace{2mm} #2}}{}
   }
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\part{\@title}\curriculumvitae}
\def\listofattachments{\listoftables}
\let\attachment\part
```

**cover.tex**:

```
\recepient{River Tech\\Main Street 127\\87630 Waterfall}
\subject{Application as Warehouse Assistant at River Tech}
\coverletter[sender=true, vspace=4mm]

Dear Sir or Madam,\\

I want to introduce myself as an applicant for the Warehouse position at River Tech, the leading supplier of plumbing supplies. As an experienced warehouse worker, I am confident that River Tech is an excellent place for me to utilize my skills. \\

During my previous role in a warehouse position at Crane \& Jenkins, my responsibilities included shipping and receiving products, preparing orders, sorting, placing, and organizing items, taking inventory, and upholding all safety standards. Safety has always been one of my biggest priorities in the workplace and my personal life, as my father was paralyzed in a warehouse accident when I was a child.\\

I appreciate your consideration of me as a candidate for the Warehouse position at River Tech. I look forward to hearing more about the company and the expectations of the Warehouse position.\\

Sincerely,
```

**static**: In this fold, there is a picture of the signature :

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can look for dotfill and modify there. However, a better approach would be checking otters manual, should it exist, somewhere …

Comment: I have managed to get rid of the lower lines but I still can't figure how to get rid of the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ottercv.cls, line 300ff `\newcommand{\coverletter}[1][]{%`, find this node:

```
       \node[anchor=north west, text width=\textwidth,inner sep=0pt] (adress) at ($(-\letterind,0|-head.south)-(0,2\lettersep)$) {%
           \ifthenelse{\boolean{\pgfkeysvalueof{/letter/sender}}}{\textsf{\underline{\@author, \ifx\@careof\@empty \else \@careof, \fi \@street, \@zip}}\\[1.5\lettersep]}{}%
           \@recepient};
```

and delete `\underline` , like

```
{\textsf{\underline{\@author, \ifx\@careof\@empty \else \@careof, \fi \@street, \@zip}}\\[1.5\lettersep]}{}%
```

becoming

```
{\textsf{{\@author, \ifx\@careof\@empty \else \@careof, \fi \@street, \@zip}}\\[1.5\lettersep]}{}%
```

The remaining pair of braces `{}` doesn't hurt.

[image: result]

However, looks like you didn't post all that's relevant. E.g. this is my modification to make `main.tex` compile, i.e. deleting/commenting out lots of stuff; did you know we love code which compiles? I know, Latex is difficult in the beginning. So the sooner you treat it with care and attention, the better.

```
\documentclass[fancy]{ottercv} % was missing !

%%% use 'massive', 'fancy' or 'basic' as otterCV options
%%% use 'german' for German dates, names etc.

%%% CONTACT DETAILS
\name{Ibrahim}{Otter}
\adress{Estuary Drive 12}{22850 Riverside}
\email{please@otter.me}
% \website{otters.org}
\phone{1}{23 456 789}
\born[Riverside]{1994-6-3}
% \pathtopicture[size=40mm]{static/profile.png}
%\pathtopicture[size=40mm]{static/otter.jpg}

%%% SIGNATURE
\pathtosignature[xshift=3mm, yshift=-5mm]{static/signature.png}
\city{Riverside}

%%% GEOMETRY
% \usepackage[]{showframe}

\begin{document}

\input{cover}
%\signature[name=true, date=false, hspace=1cm, vspace=10mm]
\listofattachments

%\maketitle
%\input{cv/profile}
%%\signature[hspace=1cm, vspace=5mm]
%
%\attachment[header=true]{\en{Motivational letter}\de{Motivationsschreiben}}
%\input{letters/motivation}
%
%\attachment{\de{Zeugnis}\en{School certificate}}
%\includepdf{attachments/certificate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I sincerely apologise for my oversight.

Comment: It's just a learning process ;-)